# Python - How print inner keys of json in a for loop?

Tags: python, json, for-loop

i have a json file like this

```
[
    {
        "analysis_start_time": "2020-10-24T17:29:00+00:00",
        "av_detect": 67,
        "certificates": [],
        "classification_tags": [
            "apt",
            "apt28",
            "apt29",
            "cozer",
            "cozybear",
            "cozycar",
            "cozyduke",
            "downloader",
            "dukes",
            "euroapt",
            "exploit",
            "fancybear",
            "group-4127",
            "group100",
            "group74",
            "hammertoss",
            "infostealer",
            "irontwilight",
            "minidionis",
            "officemonkeys",
            "pawnstorm",
            "qakbot",
            "seaduke",
            "sednit",
            "sofacy",
            "strontium",
            "swallowtail",
            "tag_0700",
            "tg-4127",
            "thedukes",
            "tsarteam",
            "zemot"
        ],
        "mitre_attcks": [
            {
                "attck_id": "T1046",
                "attck_id_wiki": "https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1046",
                "informative_identifiers": [],
                "informative_identifiers_count": 0,
                "malicious_identifiers": [],
                "malicious_identifiers_count": 0,
                "suspicious_identifiers": [],
                "suspicious_identifiers_count": 1,
                "tactic": "Discovery",
                "technique": "Network Service Scanning"
            },
            {
                "attck_id": "T1016",
                "attck_id_wiki": "https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1016",
                "informative_identifiers": [],
                "informative_identifiers_count": 0,
                "malicious_identifiers": [],
                "malicious_identifiers_count": 1,
                "suspicious_identifiers": [],
                "suspicious_identifiers_count": 0,
                "tactic": "Discovery",
                "technique": "System Network Configuration Discovery"
            }
        ],

}

{
        "analysis_start_time": "2020-07-10T14:39:28+00:00",
        "av_detect": 67,
        "certificates": [],
        "classification_tags": [],
        "compromised_hosts": [],
        "domains": [],
        "environment_description": "Static Analysis",
        "environment_id": null,
        "error_origin": null,
        "error_type": null,
        "extracted_files": [],
        "file_metadata": null,
        "hosts": [],
        "imphash": null,
        "interesting": false,
        "job_id": null,
        "md5": "77e7fb6b56c3ece4ef4e93b6dc608be0",
        "mitre_attcks": [],
        "processes": [],
        "sha1": "f46f84e53263a33e266aae520cb2c1bd0a73354e",
        "sha256": "5130f600cd9a9cdc82d4bad938b20cbd2f699aadb76e7f3f1a93602330d9997d",
        "sha512": "fb35607e7b1279a404927f4fb8b714aa766872d66a187af9a89955143b21785611d6073bfaf28686b4d93dba1756073b802afba82ff0e8a1272dd853ab88924a",
        "size": 23552,
        "ssdeep": null,
        "state": "SUCCESS",
        "submissions": [
            {
                "created_at": "2020-07-10T14:39:28+00:00",
                "filename": "file",
                "submission_id": "5f087da0ef7c213b097953e2",
                "url": null
            }
        ],
        "submit_name": "file",
        "tags": [],
        "target_url": null,
        "threat_level": 2,
        "threat_score": null,
        "total_network_connections": 0,
        "total_processes": 0,
        "total_signatures": 0,
        "type": "PE32+ executable (console) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows",
        "type_short": [
            "peexe",
            "64bits",
            "executable"
        ],
        "url_analysis": false,
        "verdict": "malicious",
        "vx_family": "Application.Pup"
    },

and so on (total 4 but they could be more)
```

My code is:

```
for i in jsonOut:

                    try:
                         print('- Start time '+i['analysis_start_time']+'\n')
                    except:
                         print('\n')
                         
                    try:
                         print('- Detetction: '+str(i['av_detect'])+'%\n')
                    except:
                        print('\n')
                    try:
                        
                         print('- Signatures: '+str(i['total_signatures'])+'\n')
                    except:
                        print('\n')
                        
                    try:
                         print('- Threat Level: '+str(i['threat_score'])+'\n')
                    except:
                        print('\n')
                        
                    try:
                         print('- Verdict: '+str(i['verdict'])+'\n')
                    except:
                        print('\n')
                    
                    try:
                        print('- Suspicious id: '+str(i['mitre_attcks']['suspicious_identifiers_count'])+'\n')
                    except:
                        print('\n')
                                        
                    try:
                       print('- Maliciuos id: '+str(i['mitre_attcks']['malicious_identifiers_count'])+'\n\n')
                       print('-----------------------------------------')                               
                    except:
                                        print('\n')
```

My output is but there aren't informations about 'mitre_attcks'

- Start time 2020-10-24T17:29:00+00:00
- Detetction: 67%
- Signatures: 5
- Threat Level: 99
- Verdict: malicious
- Start time 2020-07-10T14:39:28+00:00
- Detetction: 67%
- Signatures: 0
- Threat Level: None
- Verdict: malicious
- Start time 2019-01-11T20:48:12+00:00
- Detetction: 67%
- Signatures: 12
- Threat Level: 100
- Verdict: malicious
- Start time 2015-10-09T00:57:40+00:00
- Detetction: 67%
- Signatures: 7
- Threat Level: 16
- Verdict: suspicious

I tried to put another for loop after the first ---> for j in i['mitre_attcks']:
but doesn't work.
How I can solve this issue?
thank you

Comment: Just using `except:` will catch **all** errors. This is usually not what you want. It seems like you have an KeyError in you're try block, as `i['mitre_attcks']` is a list and needs to be looped over or indexed before accessing each field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't iterate through the `mitre_attcks` array, also you don't necessarily need to use the `try-except` block to check if a key is present in the dictionary, you can use the `in` operator and an `if` for that.

This is a possible solution for your problem, you just need to adjust the `"test.json"` path to the actual path of your own JSON file:

```py
import json

with open("test.json") as json_file:
    analysis_data = json.load(json_file)


report = ""
for analysis in analysis_data:

    if "analysis_start_time" in analysis:
        report += "- Start time: " + analysis["analysis_start_time"] + "\n\n"
    if "av_detect" in analysis:
        report += "- Detection: " + str(analysis["av_detect"]) + "\n\n"
    if "total_signatures" in analysis:
        report += "- Signatures: " + str(analysis["total_signatures"]) + "\n\n"
    if "threat_score" in analysis:
        report += "- Threat Level: " + str(analysis["threat_score"]) + "\n\n"
    if "verdict" in analysis:
        report += "- Verdict: " + str(analysis["verdict"]) + "\n\n"
    if "mitre_attcks" in analysis:
        report += "- Mitre Attacks: \n\n"
        for attack in analysis["mitre_attcks"]:
            if "suspicious_identifiers_count" in attack:
                report += (
                    "\t- Suspicious id: "
                    + str(attack["suspicious_identifiers_count"])
                    + "\n\n"
                )
            if "malicious_identifiers_count" in attack:
                report += (
                    "\t- Maliciuos id: "
                    + str(attack["malicious_identifiers_count"])
                    + "\n\n"
                )
            report += "\t" + "*" * 20 + "\n\n"

    report += "-" * 30 + "\n\n"

print(report)
```

Output:

```
- Start time: 2020-10-24T17:29:00+00:00

- Detection: 67%

- Mitre Attacks: 

        - Suspicious id: 1

        - Maliciuos id: 0

        ********************

        - Suspicious id: 0

        - Maliciuos id: 1

        ********************

------------------------------

- Start time: 2020-07-10T14:39:28+00:00

- Detection: 67%

- Signatures: 0

- Threat Level: None

- Verdict: malicious

- Mitre Attacks: 

------------------------------
```